# Changing geolocation with a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps, google-chrome-extension, geolocation

I've been interested in playing around with geolocation (and google maps api) for quite a while now, and was wondering how I should go about overriding the geolocation (with my own extension, NOT one that already exists in chrome web store), does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! I simply need to inject a content script into the page that overwrites the geolocation api functions and return 'false' values.